# Use of PED's by players who are not currently under contract or are recovering in the off-season

Tags: mlb, performance

Does Major League Baseball restrict former MLB players who are **not** under contract from using legally perscribed [PED's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance-enhancing_drugs) prior to coming back to play for a team? Are there restrictions on MLB players from using legally prescribed PED's in the off-season for recovery purposes?

Comment: What do you mean by "legally prescribed?" I interpreted that as "a Prohibited Substance...through a valid, medically
appropriate prescription provided by a duly licensed physician."

Comment: @edmastermind29 Your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all covered in [Major League Baseball’s Joint Drug Prevention and Treatment Program](http://mlbplayers.mlb.com/pa/pdf/jda.pdf).

---

> Does Major League Baseball restrict former MLB players who are not under
>   contract from using legally perscribed PED's prior to coming back to
>   play for a team?

If the former MLB player voluntarily and officially retires or if the former MLB player becomes under contract in the Minor League or another professional baseball league, then no.

The program covers:

> - all Players on the Major League Clubs’ 40-man rosters
> - any Player who becomes a free agent under Article XIX or Article XX of the Basic Agreement; and
> - any Player who is released from a Major League roster unless the Player voluntarily retires or signs a Minor League contract or a
>     contract with a club in an unaffiliated professional baseball league
>     (“Players”).

---

> Are there restrictions on MLB players from using legally prescribed
>   PED's in the off-season for recovery purposes?

Yes, there are restrictions. However, a player may be authorized to use a prohibited substance.

A player must receive a "Theraputic Use Exemption"  in order to use "a Prohibited Substance through a valid, medically appropriate prescription."

This is covered in the program's "Testing" section under "Therapeutic Use Exemption" (Section 3, Article I). Below states how a player would be eligible.

> A Player authorized to ingest a Prohibited Substance through a valid,
>   medically appropriate prescription provided by a duly licensed
>   physician shall receive a Therapeutic Use Exemption (“TUE”). To be
>   “medically appropriate,” the Player must have a documented medical
>   need under the standards accepted in the United States or Canada for
>   the prescription in the prescribed dosage.